# Unrecognized escape \R passed through at test.pl line 7

Tags: regex, perl

I have perl 5, version 22, (on Cygwin, so pretty new version). Using \R doesn't seem to work even though it should.

I'm just replacing double new lines with single new lines:

```
my $data = read_file($filename);
$data =~ s/\R\R/\R/g;
```

However I get the error "Unrecognized escape \R passed through at test.pl line 7."

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have a great enough version of perl.

Answer (score 5):

`\R` in a regex pattern matches a number of different line break sequences.

`\R` in a string literals (such as the replacement expression<sup>[1]</sup>) is meaningless.

Use

```
$data =~ s/(\R)\R+/$1/g;
```

Better yet,

```
$data =~ s/\R\K\R+//g;
```

---

1. Remember,

   ```
   s{...}{...}
   ```

   is the same as

   ```
   s{...}{ qq{...} }e
   ```

Comment: In the first snippet, `$1` contains the line ending matched.